# python how can string .replace() only calc the new value if the old value is found in the string

Tags: python, string, function

I have a code similar to this:

```
s = some_template
s = s.replace('<HOLDER1>',data1)
s = s.replace('<HOLDER2>',data2)
s = s.replace('<HOLDER3>',data3)
... #(about 30 similar lines)
```

where data1/data2/etc is often a call to a function or a complex expression which might take a while to calculate. for example:

```
s = some_template
s = s.replace('<HOLDER4>',long_func4(a,b,'some_flag') if c==1 else '')
s = s.replace('<HOLDER5>',long_func5(d,e).replace('.',''))
s = s.replace('<HOLDER6>',self.attr6)
s = s.replace('<HOLDER7>',f'{self.name}_{get_cur_month()}')
... #(about 30 similar lines)
```

in order to save on runtime, i want the string.replace() method to calculate the new value only if the old value is found in str. this can be achieved by:

```
if '<HOLDER1>' in s:
    s = s.replace('<HOLDER1>',data1)
if '<HOLDER2>' in s:
    s = s.replace('<HOLDER2>',data2)
if '<HOLDER3>' in s:
    s = s.replace('<HOLDER3>',data3)
...
```

but i don't like this solutions because it takes double the number of lines of code which will be really messy and also finds the old value in s twice for each holder..

any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What makes you think this is faster?

Comment: What exactly is `'<HOLDER1>'`? Is it that literal string, or a single character?

Comment: Also, don't use `str` as a variable name. You're overwriting the built-in function `str()` by doing so, which can lead to annoying and difficult to find bugs.

Comment: Also note that you can chain replacements: `s.replace(a, b).replace(c, d).replace(e, f)...`

Comment: Although 30 replacements seems excessive... what are you trying to do? And why does it involve so much replacement?

Comment: can you `zip` the data and HOLDER lists together so you can iterate over them in one loop?

Comment: This is *exactly* how `str.replace()` works already!  If the pattern isn't found in the string, the string is returned unchanged.  No check that you can possibly perform in Python code will be any faster than the check it's already doing.

Comment: @JacobIRR are you asking OP? Or are you asking the community if that's possible?

Comment: @jasonharper OP's dilemma is the fact that `datax` is possibly a very expensive operation. As far as I know, Python will still evaluate the `str.replace` argument before checking if the replacement is present.

Comment: @ddejohn I was asking the OP

Comment: i wrote str by mistake.. changed it.
the '<HOLDER1>' is a string. for example: '<PRICE_CALCULATED>'
I am loading a base template of a document from a file with lots of placeholders, replace them and then write to a new file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str` is immutable. You can't change it, only creating a new instance is allowed.

You could do something like:

```
def replace_many(replacements, s):
    for pattern, replacement in replacements:
        s = s.replace(pattern, replacement)
    return s

without_replacements = 'this_will_be_replaced, will it?'
replacements = [('this_will_be_replaced', 'by_this')]

with_replacements = replace_many(replacements, without_replacements)
```

You can easily make it lazy:

```
def replace_many_lazy(replacements, s):
    for pattern, replacement_func in replacements:
        if pattern in s:
            s = s.replace(pattern, replacement_func())
    return s

without_replacements = 'this_will_be_replaced, will it?'
replacements = [('this_will_be_replaced', lambda: 'by_this')]

with_replacements = replace_many_lazy(replacements, without_replacements)
```

...now you don't do the expensive computation unless necessary.

Comment: How does this answer OP's question?

Comment: well, obviosly, `str = ...` will take place at some point no matter what OOP hacks one uses.

Comment: What? Again, what does string immutability have to do with OP's problem?

Comment: you can override or create a new objectr from exisiting one

Comment: @ddejohn one could save some code & resources simply by mutating the same object many times in-place.

Comment: Right. Which can't be done with strings. Your answer is fine at the moment now that you've added some code, but the sentence "str is immutable. You can't change it, only creating a new instance is allowed." by itself is a non-sequitur. OP isn't trying to mutate an object in-place...

Comment: You're right, I added few more lines of code.

Comment: Hey, this really looks like the kind of solution i'm looking for because i could swap the 30 replace lines with 30 append lines to the replacements list of tuples.

I'm not sure how i should use the replacement_func() though.. I've edited the question and added some examples of the expressions I am actually using for data1/data2/etc

how can i place this in a replacement_func without calculating the result?

Comment: @RoiKarp just change every `expensive_computation()` to the `lambda: expensive_computatuon()`.